# Error message when initializing EKEventStore on OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, ekeventstore

I would like to programmatically create a new reminder in my app that runs on Mavericks.

As written in the [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EKEventStore), I tried to use the method `initWithAccessToEntityTypes` to initialize an event store:

> On OS X, use initWithAccessToEntityTypes: instead of the default init
>   method. Acceptable entity types are EKEntityMaskEvent for events and
>   EKEntityMaskReminder for reminders.

However, Xcode complained that this method is deprecated in OS X 10.9.

When using it anyway, I get the following error message:

> [com.apple.calendar.store.log] [Tried to connect to XPC persistence,
>   but connection was invalidated, retrying...]
>
> [com.apple.calendar.store.log] [Retried too many times, giving up.]
>
> [com.apple.calendar.store.log] [Couldn't start the XPC store server.
>   [Error Domain=CalPersistenceCreationDomain Code=3 "Could not create
>   XPC connection to the CalendarAgent, connection interrupted or
>   invalidated more than 5 times" UserInfo=0x6080002698c0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Could not create XPC connection to the
>   CalendarAgent, connection interrupted or invalidated more than 5
>   times}]] [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.xpc] [Creating a remote proxy
>   object for com.apple.CalendarAgent.proxy resulted in an invalid
>   connection. The connection will be removed. Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a
>   helper application." (The connection to service named
>   com.apple.CalendarAgent.proxy was invalidated.)
>   UserInfo=0x600000475e80 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service
>   named com.apple.CalendarAgent.proxy was invalidated.} (

I've searched using Google, StackOverflow, and the Mac developer forums but I could not find a way to make it work.

What can I do to initialize the event store in order to add a new reminder?

Answer (score 2):

The app was sandboxed. I changed the sandbox setting in Xcode (see screenshot) and now it works. Also, it seems that it is now possible to initialize a store simply by using:

```
self.ekEventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

[image]